# RailsObservers - NameError - undefined local variable or method comment for CommentObserver

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, observers

Rails 4.0.2

I am using rails observer to send a mail when anyone creates a comment.
This is my observer-

```
class CommentObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
   include Users::AdminsHelper 

  def after_create(comment)
    commenter = get_user(comment.user_id)
    receiver = get_receiver(commenter)
    NotificationMailer.new_comment_email(receiver,commenter).deliver
  end 

  def get_receiver(user)
    #user = get_user(comment.user_id)
    unless user.mentors.empty?
        user.mentors.first
    else
        user = get_user_by_update_id(comment.update_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Now I have two types of users mentors and mentee. So when a mentee creates a comment, everything works fine but when mentor creates a comment i get the error.

this is my partial which i render for both the users-

```
<div class="mentee-updates">
<h1>Updates</h1>
<% @previous_updates.each do |update| %>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="heading">
      <div class="user">
       <%= get_user(update.user_id).name %>
      </div>
      <div class="time"> 
        <%= "#{time_ago_in_words(update.created_at)} ago" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="update">
      <%= update.content %>
    </div>

    </br>
    <% unless update.comments.empty? %>
      <% update.comments.sort.each do |comment| %>
        <div class="comment-area">
          <div class="user"> 
            User <%= comment.user_id%>


          <% if current_user.id == comment.user_id then %>
          <%= link_to image_tag("DeleteRed.png"), comments_path(comment,update_id: update.id), remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } ,class: 'delete_icon'%>
          <% end %>  
          </div>
          <div class="text-muted">
            <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)%>
          </div>
          <div class="comment">
          <%= comment.content %>

          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </br>
    <% if current_user.has_role? :associate then %>
    <%= render partial: "comment", locals: { comment: @comment, update: update } %> 
    <% end %>
    </div>         
<% end %>
</div>
```

This is my comment partial-

```
<div class="comment_form">
      <%= form_for(@comment, remote: true,method: :post ) do |f| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'update_id', update.id %>   
        <%= f.label 'Add Comment'%>
        <%= f.text_area :content, id: 'comment' %>
        <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-sm" %>
      <% end %></br>
</div>
```

As it works fine for one type of user, i dont think there is any problem in partials.

Error message-

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-22 15:32:15 +0530
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "update_id"=>"9", "comment"=>{"content"=>",jhjnhj"}, "commit"=>"Add"}
  [1m[35mUpdate Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "updates".* FROM "updates" WHERE "updates"."id" = 9 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 4 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "comments" ("content", "created_at", "update_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["content", ",jhjnhj"], ["created_at", Tue, 22 Apr 2014 10:02:15 UTC +00:00], ["update_id", 9], ["updated_at", Tue, 22 Apr 2014 10:02:15 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 4]]
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 4 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" INNER JOIN "mentees_mentors" ON "users"."id" = "mentees_mentors"."mentor_id" WHERE "mentees_mentors"."mentee_id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["mentee_id", 4]]
  [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms

NameError - undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<CommentObserver:0x40f59f0>:
  app/models/comment_observer.rb:22:in `get_receiver'
  app/models/comment_observer.rb:13:in `after_create'
  rails-observers (0.1.2) lib/rails/observers/active_model/observing.rb:352:in `update'
  rails-observers (0.1.2) lib/rails/observers/activerecord/observer.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in define_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:375:in `_run__943343009__create__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `create_record'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create_record'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:477:in `create_or_update'
```

Comment: Kindly share the error message!

Comment: Found the error. In the get_receiver method in observer, i was not passing the comment object. Sorry to waste other's time in such a silly mistake.